# visa for extended non-EU family members

Tags: visa, family, italy

I'm an EU (Italian) national. I would like to know if the uncle of my wife can apply for a visa to Italy as non-EU extended family member and live here with us in Italy since he is dependent on us!

Comment: What is the nationality of your wife and your wife's uncle?

Comment: Since you are Italian, this will be governed by Italian national law, not EU freedom of movement rights.  From the site http://vistoperitalia.esteri.it/home/en, it appears that the only difference may be that you'll have to pay for the visa.